# Can I compare a function pointer to a function for equality?

Tags: c, function-pointers, c99

Is this valid C99 code? (I guess I'm asking whether it's portable)

```
void test(void){
return;
}

void (*fp)(void) = test;

if (fp == test){ <--- This line
    printf("Success\n");
}
```

I gather only pointers of the same type can be compared with one another, so maybe my question is whether function names like 'test' are just pointer aliases? Or maybe someone can tell me what my question is better than I can :)

Comment: Yes, `fp` will hold the address to `test` after the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine. The C standard is pretty self-explanatory in this case (C11 6.3.2.1/4):

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
>   operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with
>   type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’.

In your case `test` is an expression with function type. It gets converted to a function pointer of `void(*)(void)` type. This is a compatible pointer type with `fp`, so the `==` operator allows it.

Regarding the equality operator `==`, the standard says (C11 6.5.9, emphasis mine):

> **Two pointers compare equal if** and only if both are null pointers, **both are pointers to the same** object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or **function**,

Answer (score 3):

The code is valid ANSI C.

Actually what happens is, a function name such as `test` in your code, is automatically converted to a pointer to function.

You could change `test` to `&test`, the result is the same.